# Sum of each values of Guava Multimap

Tags: java, arraylist, guava, multimap

I created a Guava Multimap 
`ListMultimap<String,String> sampleMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();` 
And added some values which I take from a text file.
Now as an output I have

```
{Football=[10], Basketball=[1210, 1210, 1210, 120], Tennis=[1, 10, 100, 1000]}
```

I would like to sum each of the sports and find the highest sum. So expected result is

```
Basketball: 3750
```

Somehow I am stuck because I cant get the each one with `samleMultimap.get(x)` because key values are unknown and comes form text file. 
Is there any way to get the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end you want `Map<String, Integer>` where values are sums of original multimap. You can use couple views:

- [`Multimap#asMap()`](https://guava.dev/releases/28.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html#asMap--) to have `Map<K, Collection<V>>` view of your multimap,
- [`Maps#transformValues(Map, Function)`](https://guava.dev/releases/28.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#transformValues-java.util.Map-com.google.common.base.Function-) - to create a *view of a map where each value is transformed by a function*.

  ```
  Map<String, Integer> map = Maps.transformValues(multimap.asMap(), ints ->
          ints.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());
  ```

Note that if you want to perform many operations on resulted `map`, read caveat in documentation and for example do `ImmutableMap.copyOf(map)`:

> The function is applied lazily, invoked when needed. This is necessary for the returned map to be a view, but it means that the function will be applied many times for bulk operations like `Map.containsValue(java.lang.Object)` and `Map.toString()`. For this to perform well, function should be fast. To avoid lazy evaluation when the returned map doesn't need to be a view, copy the returned map into a new map of your choosing.

Answer (score 1):

With a `ListMultimap` you can call [`asMap()`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html#asMap()) to get a view as a [`java.util.Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), then do normal map things.

If you change `sampleMultimap` to be an [`ArrayListMultimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) instead of `ListMultimap`, then you can call [`keySet()`](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html#keySet--) directly (skip the `asMap()` call) and iterate over the resulting keys.

Here's an example showing how you could get each key from a `ListMultimap` (even if the underlying implementation is an instance of `ArrayListMultimap`), then get each associated value:

```
ListMultimap<String,String> sampleMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
Map<String,String> mapView = sampleMultimap.asMap();
for (String key : mapView.keySet()) {
    String value = mapView.get(key);
    // do something with value
}
```